# How to highlighted a particular location in html div on click Marker on MAP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have `Div` in which I have 2-3 inner `divs` with unique id`s, having locations details in each`div`, Now I have a Map on which I am displaying all locations on Load as markers on map. So Now I want to highlight a particular location on click any marker on map.

```
<div>
    <div id = "Location1">Location1</div>
    <div id = "Location2">Location2</div>
    <div id = "Location3">Location3</div>
</div>
```

I am using marker `gmap` marker. How can I override the `addListener` function of Map.

Js file included Library as well

```
$.get(Routing.generate('light_box', {id: id}), function(data){
$('#locationsG-map').mapmarker({
       // zoom  : 14,
        center  : 'London',
        markers : data,            
    });

google.addListener('click', function () {           
        myCustomFunction(locationID)
    });
```

Click not working here I want to call custom function "myCustomFunction" here to highlighted a particular location on click. Please guide

Thanks in Advance